# Android PhotoPicker returns NULL URI

Tags: android, android-activity, android-jetpack

```
ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickImage = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(), uri -> {

        if(uri==null) {
            //URI always NULL here
        } else {
            //Never reached
        }


    });
```

```
pickImage.launch(new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
                        .setMediaType(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE)
                        .build());
```

I have tried the same code in a new project and it is returning a valid URI. But PhotoPicker returns a NULL URI in my project. Any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: Try without setmediaType(). Which Android version on device?

Comment: What lifecycle method did you call it?

Comment: @blackapps, I have tried without setMediaType(). Same result. The device is running Android 13.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez I have called it in onCreate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, PhotoPicker (or ActivityResultLauncher in general) fails if onActivityResult() is also Overridden in the Activity. I removed that and now PhotoPicker is returning a valid URI.